# using wp_redirect to redirect to a permalink

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, wp-redirect

I'm using wp_redirect to change the URL of my 404 page:

```
function show_404($message = 'page not found'){
   wp_redirect(home_url() . '/error/404?m=' . urlencode($message));
   exit();
}
```

I have created a wordpress page that has a `/error/` permalink. It works fine on my local WAMP environment (properly showing my themed 404 page when navigating to `localhost/wordpress/pageThatDNE`), but when I test it to a real server, I get a `The requested URL /error/404 was not found on this server.` message. Navigating to `mysite.com/error/` gives me a `You don't have permission to access /error/ on this server.` message. My other pages/permalinks work fine.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is looking for the page 404, which is a child of the page /error. Try just doing this:

```
function show_404($message = 'page not found'){
   wp_redirect(home_url() . '/error?m=' . urlencode($message));
   exit();
}
```

But your doing it wrong.

You should just use [WordPress's internal 404 page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page), it will save a lot more headaches that will arise in the future. It is as simple as creating a template of 404.php in your current theme directory.

Comment: I did--in fact, page-error.php just contains `require_once('404.php')`, but I need to change the URL to match the original site. My solution was using wp_redirect and a page. Is there an easier way to change the 404's URL?